# find field with highest record

Tags: sql

I have this table:

server_records: id int (AUTO_INCREMENT), record int, time int

If I wanna get the field with the highest record how do i do that?

```
SELECT `record` FROM `server_records` WHERE `record` = highest?!
```

Comment: Do you want to get the highest id or the record with the highest id?

Comment: I think he wants the record (row) with the highest 'record'. Yes, he has a field named record :)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM server_records
ORDER BY record desc
```

MYSql:

```
SELECT * FROM server_records
ORDER BY record desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The highest **record**, not id, correct?

```
SELECT MAX(record)
  FROM server_records
```

or, if you want all fields:

```
SELECT *
  FROM server_records
    WHERE record = 
      ( SELECT MAX(record)
          FROM server_records
      )
```

Comment: Do you know how the performance of your second piece of code would compare to the `order by` method?

Comment: If there is no index on the record field, I'd guess terribly. But wouldn't the `ORDER BY` method be as well slow?

Comment: I think I'd have to run it and take a look to give an accurate answer.  Just curious if you knew off the top of your head.